Can't fetch all the section elements using find_elements with Selenium
I've been trying to use the find_elements() method of Selenium to extract the  element of a webpage, there are 3 elements but the code is only fetching the first one.
This is the code I'm using:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url = f"https://www.latamairlines.com/us/en/flight-offers?origin=BOG&inbound=2024-07-15T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&outbound=2024-07-01T12%3A00%3A00.000Z&destination=MDE&adt=1&chd=0&inf=0&trip=RT&cabin=Economy&redemption=false&sort=RECOMMENDED"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--incognito')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options = options)
driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, './/button[@class="sc-dAbbOL dxkJUk sc-fHjqPf sc-bHvAfQ lmJCPj jshqAF"]'))).click()

driver.implicitly_wait(10)

flights = driver.find_elements(by = By.XPATH, value = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li')

WebDriverWait(flights[18], 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li[19]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a'))).click()
WebDriverWait(flights[18], 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li[19]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/dialog/div/div[1]/article/div')))
itineraries = flights[18].find_elements(by = By.XPATH, value = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li[19]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/dialog/div/div[1]/article/div')
print(itineraries)

This image is a portion of the webpage that I'm scrapping.
The URL of the webpage is webpage
I used the same code to fetch all the <li> elements of the same webpage and it worked, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong with the <section> elements, so how can I do to fetch the 3 section elements?

Please clarify why you're indexing flights by 18 and what the expected output should be

I chose 18 since it was the first flight to have 3 section elements and I wanted to see if what I'd done with the code was working, but it should work with any other index. I want to fetch the flight information from the section elements, and I need to iterate through them to fetch it.

the site uses an api, it's much faster/cleaner to scrape that instead

can't you find simpler xpath for elements? Can't you use some class or ID or any other unique value? Maybe browser/JavaScript adds some elements and your long xpath doesn't match to elements.

newer Selenium can automatically download driver so it allows to use webdriver.Chrome(option=options) without service

you could add all import to create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run.

XPATH of "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li" is a selector for a single element.

I registered for the API but haven't got an answer yet. I tried finding the elements by class or ID and it didn't work, I got the same result. When I use "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div/div/ol/li" it returns all 21 flights, I tried using a similar path for the section elements but it didn't work.
